# How to toggle class inside a specific child element when the parent element is clicked using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When a parent button is clicked, a class is toggled inside its child element to show or hide and when that child element is clicked it will display a loading animation for few seconds and toggle back the child element to it's original state which is hidden.

I tried to add follow the pure vanilla JS but couldn't get it to work properly. I have done the adding show class when the parent class is clicked but the loading animation is where I got stucked.

Comment: Hello there! A few more details can help us determine the best way to answer this question. Please provide a code example.

Comment: Please post the code you are referencing that isn't working so we can help you fix it. Include all HTML, CSS and JS needed to minimally reproduce the issue you are not able to solve.

Comment: You can not have a parent button you certainly mean a parent element (div for example) that when clicked toggle a class in child element.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript as follow to only toggle the .show-white class on .child-1 element when only the parent element is clicked (not the childs, for this I use the condition (if(e.target!==e.currentTarget).

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent')
const childOne = document.querySelector('.child-1')
const childTwo = document.querySelector('.child-2')


parent.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    if(e.target!==e.currentTarget){
        return
    }
    childOne.classList.toggle('show-white')
})
```

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.child-1{
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child-2{
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green;
}

.show-white{
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```